# Using AutoMapper and CRUD operations in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am having trouble using AutoMapper when doing CRUD operations in MVC. I have scoured the web looking for something related to this but cant find anything related to what I am trying to do. Maybe there is something but I am having trouble understanding the more advanced functions of AutoMapper.

Basically what im trying to do is use AutoMapper on the CREATE method in an MVC application. Now I can map just the basic information perfectly fine but when I need to include another Model I get completely lost in figuring it out. Here is my example below.

This is the model in my AppDomainClasses

```
public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Cities = new List<City>();
    }
    public City(string cityName)
    {
        this.Name = cityName;
        this.Cities = new List<City>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

This is my viewmodel in which im trying to automap

```
public class CityForList
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CityFull : CityForList
{
    public CityFull()
    {
        Cities = new List<CityForList>();
    }

    public List<CityForList> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

So basically when I created this Map

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CityFull, City>();
```

Then I pass a CityFull object into the mapper

```
Mapper.Map<CityFull, City>(cf);
```

So what I am doing is that I have the Create method passing in the CityFull object and a FormCollection of items which contains the ids of the cities. So all I need to have done is map the Id, the Name and the cities that were selected and have them mapped. Now I can map the Id and Name without problem but I do not know how to then add the selected cities ( comes from the form collection of a listbox) into AutoMapper to include them in the mapping.

I thank you ahead of time for any help you can offer!

Comment: You should be able to model bind the entire `CityFull` class (rather than using `FormCollection`), including children--then automap the instance to an instance of the `City` class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get the selected cities is because the "Selected" attribute is not part of the "City" Class.

I would advise you to make another map with AutoMapper, that maps the controller's to a class(Lets call it CityController) that you will create , and have that CityController related to CityForList.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean. What I've done is converted the selected cities from the FormCollection into a list of CitiesForList which I am then trying to map to the into CityFull along with the Id and Name which already work fine. All I need to know is how I can also map that list into my map I created the first time.